# Inserting JavaScript output into Database with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

The title is a bit more vague than the task I'm trying to complete, so I'm going to explain this as clearly as I can.

What I'm trying to do is run a JavaScript command within a PHP script, however, it seems like the JavaScript only executes after the PHP has finished, which means it basically does nothing. Another thought I had was the header is an image type (JPEG), and I'm not exactly sure if that would be affecting it, but it seems like it could be since the PHP is executing first.

Here's the JavaScript embedded into the PHP;

```
Function GetResolution(){
    Echo '<script>document.write(screen.width + " x " + screen.height)</script>';
}
```

I need resolution depending on screen size for resizing images, but on topic, I need that code to run in as-is after the header content type is set. So basically, I'm executing that function after

```
Header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP code is executed in the server. Javascript is executed in the client. That means that PHP only echoes the script to the client (but will never execute it). If you need to store in a database the result of the execution of a given javascript, you'll need to make an AJAX call for it.

Besides, I don't see where the 'inserting output into database' takes place in your code.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant by vague. I'll need to put the JavaScript resolution output into the database, and I didn't know how to explain it as well, lol.

Comment: Alright, so what is exactly what you'd like to store? the size of the rendered image?

Comment: Sort of, I need both the resolution of the page and the rendered image (which I'm using to update depending on changes made to the webpage) but thanks, the AJAX call is working.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you sorted that out!